# Storing a function in json [Javascript/Coffeescript]

Tags: javascript, json, coffeescript

I have a config, and in it I want to determine a function to be used in some code later:

```
get_config = () ->
    {
        "function" : (stuff) ->
            stuff + "more stuff"
    }
```

This code is called somewhere, and the config is stored as json in a file, using the following helper function:

```
stringifyWithFunctions = (object, replacer, spacing) ->
    stringify_functions = (key, val) ->
        if replacer
            if typeof val == 'function'
                return replacer(key, val.toString())
            else
                return replacer(key, val)
        else
            if typeof val == 'function'
                return val.toString()
            else
                return val

    return JSON.stringify(object, stringify_functions, spacing)
```

I end up with a json object that looks like this:

```
{ 'function' : 'function (stuff) {return stuff + "more stuff"}' }
```

However, I can't figure out a good way to load this function later.

```
loaded_function = eval(config['function'])
```

Results in an error "Unexpected token (" and I feel as if there's likely a cleaner way of doing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the config JSON is stored as a static file and used over and over, a clean solution would be to simply remove the quotes from around the function(s) in the JSON and then do this:

```
var get_config = eval("(" + json_data + ")");
```

The JSON needs to be wrapped in parenthesis to evaluate, that's why you're getting the error. If the config JSON is constantly needing to be stringified then there's a couple of other options. You could do this to call the function:

```
var get_config = eval("(" + json_data + ")");

eval("(" + get_config.afunction + ")")("this is passed to the function");
```

or you can use the JSONfn plugin (http://www.eslinstructor.net/jsonfn/) to stringify the JSON instead of the functions you're using and just eval it like above. The JSONfn plugin is able to serialize functions like you're needing to do.

Here's a jsFiddle to mess with that shows the above code in use: http://jsfiddle.net/4UP53/

Comment: `function(...) { ... }` is seen as a function *declaration* by `eval` but `(function(...){...})` is seen as a function *expression* so you can `eval` the latter.

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have explained that more.

Comment: I was writing something that was basically your answer plus my comment when your answer came in. I filled in the blanks with a comment rather than a mostly duplicated answer. No worries.

Comment: This is technically correct, but I wonder if there's a better pattern to accomplish what I'm trying to do. The best I've come up with is keeping a module of potential functions somewhere, and putting the name of one in the config.

Comment: Is the config JSON programmatically updated? Or is it static?

Comment: in this case it is static (changes from one job to the next)

Comment: Then if you just remove the quotes wrapping the functions from the JSON, that would be the simplest solution.

Comment: @mavix I kind of like the "module of potential functions" approach, then you'd be doing a tiny bit of parsing to convert the names to functions and you'd get function whitelisting for free.

Comment: @aecend do you mean storing the function directly? Because functions are invalid json unfortunately